# How to add Column in SharePoint through MuleSoft

Tags: mulesoft

I'm trying to create **Column** in SharePoint through **MuleSoft**
In the SharePoint there is add column in that, there is choice in drop down, and I want to add one more choice in that drop down through **MuleSoft AnyPoint Studio**

Please Guide me.
Thanks

Comment: The question is very unclear. Can you explain where exactly is the add column ? Is it in a mule connector? or somewhere in sharepoint itself?

Comment: I want to add the column in the List field on my org and I have to do that process through the Mulesoft REST API.

Comment: Unfortunately it still not clear. Please provide more details and examples to clarify the question.

Comment: My question is I want to add a new column in the list section on SharePoint with the help of Mulesoft. For example, My list name is "Rating" and I wanna add a new column in the Rating List with some fields. Like: Hot, Cold, and Warm.